# convert from hostnames to ip address and vice versa

Tags: domain-name

What if two or more different domains which are not alias(using Cname) are hosted on the same server?

There are two perspectives :

1. How a server with same IP address resolves two different host names ?
2. As a user/client  can I know how server resolves the hostname and  assign some unique ID to different domain names using which they can be distinctly identified ?

Answer (score 1):

Name to IP and IP to name is different operations ans are configured differently. So it is possible for a lot names to point to one IP and IP can point only to one name. Second part is not quite correct, but its easier to understand so. Please, read about DNS (Domain Name System) to learn further.